# how to get bind param array in Yii create command

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Is there any way in yii to get the array of the parameters passed in createCommand?

```
     $countSQL= 'my sql query ';
     $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($countSQL);   
     $command->bindValue(":param1",'%'.$param1.'%');
     $command->bindValue(":param2",'%'.$param2.'%');
     $command->queryAll();
```

I want to know if it there is any way to get the array which will be similar to

```
array(
 ":param1" => '%'.$param1.'%',
 ":param2" => '%'.$param2.'%',
)
```

Comment: Use the bindValues() method.http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#bindValues-detail

Answer (score 1):

You can get those parameters but only with extending some library files like PDO Connection and CDbCommand.

In my project, I had created extended CPdoConnection and CDbCommand.

I had code for you, let me know if you need it.

Regards,
Sanjay